# The import org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator cannot be resolved

Tags: hibernate-validator

I am working on a demo example that demonstrates the  use of Hibernate's

```
validation API.

I'm trying to use the ClassValidator class.

But the import required for it,  

org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator<User.class> is not getting resolved.

I also have the compatible dependencies
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.2.4.Final</version>
```

```
<hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Comment: Try by adding hibernate annotation jars

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I added this. It doesn't help. I fetched the dependency from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.5.6-Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Update the following

<!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>3.0.0.GA</hibernate.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The example is hibernate 4.2 and then you want to go back to 3.5.6? Not really a solution for the future.